# When returning the Not Found / 404 Page within App.js

Tags: react-router

Currently building a React application utilizing React Router. Within my switch statement, after I have set up all my primary routes to their exact locations, my final bit of code before the closing switch statement looks a bit like this...

```
    <Route component={NotFound} />
    <Redirect to="/not-found" />
</Switch>
```

Curious if the `Redirect` in this case is necessary? Redundant? Good practice to give the not found page its own path i.e. `<Route exact path="/not-found" component={NotFound} />`?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I actually think your better off without the redirect that way the person can see the url they typed in.  That way they can check the spelling to make sure they entered the correct url.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really required. You can simply put `path="*"` in your route, so if the user visits some unknown route they stay on the same URL but they can still see the NotFound component.

Comment: I dont think you even need to put a path prop in the route.  In the switch statement it will find the first match so if nothing matches you can just use `<Route component={NotFound}/>` at the end and it will return the not found component if nothing else matches.

Comment: True. It depends on your preference. I usually set the path and component props in a table-like format using tab indentations so I set the path prop as well, but it works without that. However Redirect isn't required here in this question.